# How to trim a field that's been excluded from display?

Tags: 7, entities

In Views, in order to group certain fields inside a common div, i excluded them from display and inserted them in a global text field by using their 'replacement pattern references'.

Here's what the div looks like :

```
<div class="nodetitle">[title]</div>
<div class="date-author"><span>[name]</span> - <span>[created]</span></div>
<div class="readmore"><a href="[path]">More details &raquo;</a></div>
```

The thing is i wanted to trim the node title to 50 characters max.
Trimming works fine when displaying the field 'as is' but not when it's been used as a replacement pattern in a different field.

Any help on how to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've double checked your problem and it seems to works like a charm.

1. In your view go to Field -> Title -> [edit] -> Rewrite results -> Trim this field to a maximum length -> set maximum length to 50
   [image]
2. Add Global: Custom text field and place [title] in text field.
   [image]

Result should looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I'm so ashamed of myself, i was trimming the wrong field, that's why it had no effect. Thank you ;)